# Read/Send sms via 3g modem in firefox addon sdk

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have 3g modem, and I need read/send sms from that modem in my firefox addon. How can i do it? I read about sms-npm but i do not uderstant how to use it. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Comment: Sounds like an awesome addon. Can you link us to the sms-npm source, we can then tell you how to conver that, or maybe even possibly import that module itself.

Comment: Eventually i try to use modem-npm. I read some information about AT-commands to 3g modem [link](https://github.com/emilsedgh/modem) and I think this package suit me, but I can't successfully install it via            npm install modem. I get in install process that:   **bold**     C:\Users\myFirefox-addon>npm install modem                                      > serialport@2.0.0 install C:\Users\myFirefox-addon\node_modules\modem\node_modu
les\serialport
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

(node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio
instead.

Comment: So I asked the jpm experts and they told me this: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/00d9da59c0691046f212

Comment: Can I use c++ dll via js-ctypes?

Comment: You can do anything with js-ctypes. :) Let me know if you need help I think you got a great project going here. Join on the jsctype channel if you need help: irc://moznet/jsctypes or html5 irc client mibbit: https://client02.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsctypes